# Convert pg (postgress node module) native from require to import

Tags: node.js, postgresql, import, ecmascript-6

I use a transpiler to convert es6 / typescript code to es5.
Here is the original es5 code with pg native module import for node js:

```
var pg  = require('pg').native
```

With es6/typsecript mode I use:

```
import * as pge from "pg"
```

Which works fine but I can't find the syntax  to specify the .native so it get transpiled correctly to require('pg').native

I tried :

```
import * as pge from "pg"
export let pg       = pge.native
```

But i'm not sure if this is the proper way. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
import { native as pg } from 'pg';
```

Which is the same as:

```
var pg = require('pg').native;
```

You'd then use the `pg` variable as you would.

Comment: seems to work but tslint says "pg has no export member native".. I guess it is a problem with definition and doesn't prevent this to work, do you know how could I get rid of ths error ?

Comment: You'll need the package definitions, luckily these exist on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e937b3e64af586d19f2ea29fdf771e9dc4feecc8/pg/pg.d.ts).

Comment: Just out of leak question. How to close pg connection? I have tried pg.end() but it is not working. Here is my original question https://stackoverflow.com/q/48617031/2547005

Answer (score 2):

This is how I end up using and it's working fine.

```
import PG from 'pg';

const Pool = PG.Pool;

export const connection  =  new Pool({
    user: 'xxxxx',
    host: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    port: xxxx,
  });
```